# What do these qr{} regular expressions mean?

Tags: regex, perl

What do these mean?

```
qr{^\Q$1\E[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*\Q$2\E$}i
qr{^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*\Q$1\E$}i
```

If `$pattern` is a Perl regular expression, what is `$identity` in the code below?

```
$identity =~ $pattern;
```

Comment: What do you mean by “identity”? Do you mean mathematical identity? If yes, how do you define the output of `=~` operator (which context: list/scalar)? What part of the regex don't you understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The binding operator `=~` applies a regex to a string variable. This is documented in [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators)

The `\Q ... \E` escape sequence is a way to quote meta characters (also documented in perlop). It allows for variable interpolation, though, which is why you can use it here with `$1` and `$2`. However, using those variables inside a regex is somewhat iffy, because they themselves are defined during the use of a capture inside a regex.

The character class bracket `[ ... ]` defines a range of characters which it will match. The quantifier that follows it `*` means that particular bracket must match zero or more times. The dashes denote ranges, such as `a-z` meaning "from a through z". The escaped dash `\-` means a literal dash.

The `^` and `$` (the dollar sign at the end) denotes anchors, beginning and end of string respectively. The modifier `i` at the end means the match is case insensitive.

In your example, `$identity` is a variable that presumably contains a string (or whatever it contains will be converted to a string).

Answer (score 5):

When the RHS of `=~` isn't `m//`, `s///` or `tr///`, a match operator (`m//`) is implied.

```
$identity =~ $pattern;
```

is the same as

```
$identity =~ /$pattern/;
```

It matches the pattern or pre-compiled regex `$pattern` (`qr//`) against the value of `$identity`.

Answer (score 1):

The [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) documentation is your friend here. Search it for unfamiliar regex constructs.

A detailed explanation is below, but it is so hairy that I wonder whether using a module such as [Text::Balanced](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3A%3ABalanced) would be a superior approach.

---

The first pattern matches possibly empty *delimited* strings, and the delimiters are in `$1` and `$2`, which we do not know until runtime. Say `$1` is `(` and `$2` is `)`, then the first pattern matches strings of the form

- `()`
- `(a)`
- `(9)`
- `(abcABC_012-)`
- and so on …

The second pattern matches *terminated* strings, where the terminator is in `$1`—also not known until runtime. Assuming the terminator is `]`, then the second pattern matches strings of the form

- `]`
- `a]`
- `Aa9a_9]`

Using `\Q...\E` around a pattern removes any special *regex* meaning from the characters inside, as documented in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators):

> For the pattern of regex operators (`qr//`, `m//` and `s///`), the quoting from `\Q` is applied after interpolation is processed, but before escapes are processed. This allows the pattern to match literally (except for `$` and `@`). For example, the following matches:
>
> ```
> '\s\t' =~ /\Q\s\t/
> ```
>
> Because `$` or `@` trigger interpolation, you'll need to use something like `/\Quser\E\@\Qhost/` to match them literally.

The patterns in your question *do* want to trigger interpolation but do *not* want any regex metacharacters to have special meaning, as with parentheses and square brackets above that are meant to match literally.

Other parts:

- Circumscribed brackets delimit a *character class*. For example, `[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]` matches any single character that is upper- or lowercase A through Z (but with no accents or other extras), zero through nine, underscore, or hyphen. Note that the hyphen is escaped at the end to emphasize that it matches a literal hyphen rather and does not specify part of a range.
- The `*` quantifier means match zero or more of the preceding subpattern. In the examples from your question, the star repeats character classes.
- The patterns are bracketed with `^` and `$`, which means an entire string must match rather than some substring to succeed.
- The `i` at the end, after the closing curly brace, is a regex switch that makes the pattern case-insensitive. As TLP helpfully points out in the comment below, this makes the delimiters or terminators match without regard to case if they contain letters.

The expression `$identity =~ $pattern` tests whether the compiled regex stored in `$pattern` (created with `$pattern = qr{...}`) matches the text in `$identity`. As written above, it is likely being evaluated for its side effect of storing capture groups in `$1`, `$2`, etc. This is a red flag. **Never** use `$1` and friends unconditionally but instead write

```
if ($identity =~ $pattern) {
  print $1, "\n";  # for example
}
```

Comment: `\Q$1\E` does *not* match a literal dollar sign, it interpolates the variable. Also, the `i` modifier is not redundant, as it works dynamically with the content inside `$1` and `$2` (although I almost thought so too).